City under attack turns missles to dust. Dust destroys city defences
I read this book back in the early seventies in the UK. It was in the form of a double sided book or magazine. Like the Ace doubles listed here.
A city of people was under bombardment from an enemy. The anti missile system of the city turned the incoming missiles to dust making the city population think they had the situation under control. Then the dust was somehow activated destroying the defense system.

A double sided paperback book could be one of the Ace doubles.  https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pubseries.cgi?1  There were several hundred of them published.

That was the exact format I have added your information to the question.

The Mad Metropolis by Philip E. High, Ace Double #M-135.
The city is controlled by an intelligent computer, with links to all electronic devices in the metropolis.
The attacker outside sends a steady barrage of missiles. The computer automatically destroys each missile with the city air defense, but otherwise pays them no heed.
But the missiles are a trap. They are composed of a carefully engineered alloy. When destroyed, they turn into microscopic metallic dust which drifts into the city. This is not noticed by the computer.
In the city, the dust is attracted to electrical circuits. It gathers on all wires. The computer doesn't notice this either.
When enough dust has accumulated, the attackers broadcast tuned energy into the city. The dust absorbs the energy, and is heated hot enough to destroy the circuits it is clinging to.
All over the city thousands of items of vital electrical equipment are instantly destroyed.

Great I will accept that although the book summaries online do not mention this as part of the plot your description is spot on and it was available as an Ace double.

@RoyC I found a copy and it indeed does match. There was a curious bluish haze which changed rapidly to brilliant white and, in the immediate area, incredible heat. The dust began to eat its way through the installations like molten lead through butter.

@Shawn given Winchell's rep I did not doubt it. Found a copy on Kindle will read it shortly.
